# Sources for multiple Stieltjes integral

Tags: integration, reference-request, lebesgue-integral, stieltjes-integral

I'd like to study more on multiple Stieltjes integral and want to know which sources (books or papers) provide a detailed discussion of multiple Riemann–Stieltjes integral or multiple Lebesgue-Stieltjes integral.

Comment: Carter and van Brunt's "The Lebesgue-Stieltjes Integral: A Practical Introduction" chapter 7 is "Double and Repeated Integrals".